# click button selenium python

Tags: python, automation

I am newbie in Selenium then I have element for Login button as attachment.

[login.but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eioUE.png)

Can you guys help me to get xpath for this button? I tried this xpath but it's wrong

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `CSS` selector:

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-contained.elementor-button")
```

The idea is to add classes with dots without spaces between them.

`XPATH` will be trickier:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'MuiButtonBase-root Muibutton-contained MuiButton-contained elementor-button')]")
```

You can add or remove classes in this locator. The main idea - locator must be unique.
Also, there may be some typos in class names I wrote. I had to type them manually as you did not provide any code snippet. So, be careful with typos.